# scikit learn example no longer working?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to simply run the script at

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_stock_market.html

However it gives

```
File "./sparsecov-example.py", line 92, in <module>
    for symbol in symbols]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/finance.py", line 236, in quotes_historical_yahoo
    fh = fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker, date1, date2, cachename)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/finance.py", line 197, in fetch_historical_yahoo
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url)) as urlfh:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Is the financial data no longer available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some stock symbols have changed or disappeared. Try the [latest version of the example](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_stock_market.html), which has been fixed to deal with this.